# Connection timed out android studio android pie version 9

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

I created android application grocery app using android studio. when i open some devices it showing connection timed out keep on loading. but some other devices working. please check attached screenshot. please tell me which code i need to check

Thank you

Note : Especially Android 9 Pie Mobile devices getting this error
[image: error screenshot on some mobile devices]

Mainactivity.java

```
package woodland.bharati;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.style.URLSpan;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import Config.BaseURL;
import Config.SharedPref;
import Fonts.CustomTypefaceSpan;
import Fragment.About_us_fragment;
import Fragment.Contact_Us_fragment;
import Fragment.Empty_cart_fragment;
import Fragment.Home_fragment;
import Fragment.Cart_fragment;
import Fragment.Reward_fragment;
import Fragment.Edit_profile_fragment;
import Fragment.Shop_Now_fragment;
import Fragment.Terms_and_Condition_fragment;
import Fragment.Wallet_fragment;
import woodland.bharati.networkconnectivity.NetworkError;
import util.ConnectivityReceiver;
import util.DatabaseHandler;
import util.Session_management;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private TextView totalBudgetCount, totalBudgetCount2, totalBudgetCount3, tv_name, powerd_text;
    private ImageView iv_profile;
    private DatabaseHandler dbcart;
    private Session_management sessionManagement;
    private Menu nav_menu;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView mTitle;
    LinearLayout viewpa;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String language="";
    LinearLayout My_Order, My_Reward, My_Walllet, My_Cart;
    int padding = 0;
    private TextView txtRegId;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    LinearLayout Change_Store;
    String Store_Count;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {



                newBase = LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase);

                super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
            }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("MYTAG", "This is your Firebase token" + token);

        sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("lan", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


         editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

         editor.putString("language", "english");



              if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

                if (key.equals("MainActivity") && value.equals("True")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
            subscribeToPushService();
        }


        Store_Count = SharedPref.getString(MainActivity.this, BaseURL.KEY_STORE_COUNT);


//

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setPadding(padding, toolbar.getPaddingTop(), padding, toolbar.getPaddingBottom());


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;

                Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/Bold.ttf");
                textView.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
            }


        }
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.name));


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }


        dbcart = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        checkConnection();

        sessionManagement = new Session_management(MainActivity.this);


        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

            //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
            SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
            if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                    applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
                }
            }

            //the method we have create in activity
            applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
        }

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x80000000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        nav_menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        View header = ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);
        Change_Store = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.change_store_btn);
        viewpa=(LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.viewpa);
        if (sessionManagement.isLoggedIn()) {
            viewpa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        if (Store_Count.equals("1")) {
            Change_Store.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (Store_Count.equals("2")) {
            Change_Store.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Change_Store.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectStore.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }
            });
        }
        iv_profile = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.iv_header_img);
        tv_name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_header_name);
        My_Order = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.my_orders);
        My_Reward = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.my_reward);
        My_Walllet = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.my_wallet);
        My_Cart = (LinearLayout) header.findViewById(R.id.my_cart);

        My_Order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, My_Order_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        My_Reward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fm = new Reward_fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        My_Walllet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fm = new Wallet_fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        My_Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (dbcart.getCartCount() > 0) {
                    Fragment fm = new Cart_fragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Item in Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        iv_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sessionManagement.isLoggedIn()) {
                    Fragment fm = new Edit_profile_fragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        updateHeader();

        sideMenu();


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fm = new Home_fragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm, "Home_fragment")
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit();
        }
        getFragmentManager().

                addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        try {
                            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                            Fragment fr = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentPanel);

                            final String fm_name = fr.getClass().getSimpleName();
                            Log.e("backstack: ", ": " + fm_name);
                            if (fm_name.contentEquals("Home_fragment")) {
                                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                                toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                                toggle.syncState();

                            } else if (fm_name.contentEquals("My_order_fragment") ||
                                    fm_name.contentEquals("Thanks_fragment")) {
                                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

                                toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                                toggle.syncState();

                                toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        Fragment fm = new Home_fragment();
                                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                                                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {

                                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

                                toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                                toggle.syncState();

                                toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                        onBackPressed();
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });


//        if (sessionManagement.getUserDetails().
//                get(BaseURL.KEY_ID) != null && !sessionManagement.getUserDetails().
//                get(BaseURL.KEY_ID).equalsIgnoreCase())
//
//        {
//            MyFirebaseRegister fireReg = new MyFirebaseRegister(this);
//            fireReg.RegisterUser(sessionManagement.getUserDetails().get(BaseURL.KEY_ID));
//        }

    }


    public void updateHeader() {
        if (sessionManagement.isLoggedIn()) {
            String getname = sessionManagement.getUserDetails().get(BaseURL.KEY_NAME);
            String getimage = sessionManagement.getUserDetails().get(BaseURL.KEY_IMAGE);
            String getemail = sessionManagement.getUserDetails().get(BaseURL.KEY_EMAIL);
            SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String previouslyEncodedImage = shre.getString("image_data", "");
            if (!previouslyEncodedImage.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                byte[] b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                iv_profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
//            Glide.with(this)
//                    .load(BaseURL.IMG_PROFILE_URL + getimage)
//                    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon)
//                    .crossFade()
//                    .into(iv_profile);
            tv_name.setText(getname);

        }
    }


    private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Font/Bold.ttf");
        SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
    }


    public void sideMenu() {

        if (sessionManagement.isLoggedIn()) {
            //  tv_number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setVisible(true);
            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_powerd).setVisible(true);

//            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_user).setVisible(true);
        } else {

            //tv_number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv_name.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.btn_login));
            tv_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setVisible(false);

            //            nav_menu.findItem(R.id.nav_user).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void setFinish() {
        finish();
    }

    public void setCartCounter(String totalitem) {
        try {
            totalBudgetCount.setText(totalitem);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        item.setVisible(true);

        View count = item.getActionView();
        count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                menu.performIdentifierAction(item.getItemId(), 0);
            }
        });

        totalBudgetCount = (TextView) count.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
        totalBudgetCount.setText("" + dbcart.getCartCount());
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.action_language){
            openLanguageDialog();
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
            if (dbcart.getCartCount() > 0) {
                Fragment fm = new Cart_fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else {
                Fragment fm = new Empty_cart_fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void openLanguageDialog() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_language,null,false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(v);
        TextView lEnglish = v.findViewById(R.id.l_english);
        TextView lSpanish = v.findViewById(R.id.l_arabic);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        lEnglish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(getApplication(),"en");
                getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
                editor.putString("language", "english");
                editor.apply();


                recreate();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        lSpanish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          LocaleHelper.setLocale(getApplication(),"ar");
                getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("language", "spanish");
                editor.apply();



                recreate();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fm = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if (id == R.id.nav_shop_now) {
            fm = new Shop_Now_fragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_profile) {
            fm = new Edit_profile_fragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_support) {
            String smsNumber = "919886143091";
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
            sendIntent.putExtra("jid",     PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(smsNumber)+"@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix
            startActivity(sendIntent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus) {
            toolbar.setTitle("About");
            fm = new About_us_fragment();
            args.putString("url", BaseURL.GET_ABOUT_URL);
            args.putString("title", getResources().getString(R.string.nav_about));
            fm.setArguments(args);
        }
             else if (id == R.id.nav_youtube) {
                toolbar.setTitle("Videos");
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://woodlandbharati.com/videos/"));
            startActivity(myWebLink);

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_enquiry) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Enquiry Us");
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://woodlandbharati.com/enquiry/"));
            startActivity(myWebLink);



        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_health) {
            toolbar.setTitle("Health Tips");
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://woodlandbharati.com/news/"));
            startActivity(myWebLink);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_policy) {
            fm = new Terms_and_Condition_fragment();
            args.putString("url", BaseURL.GET_TERMS_URL);
            args.putString("title", getResources().getString(R.string.nav_terms));
            fm.setArguments(args);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_review) {
            //reviewOnApp();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
            fm = new Contact_Us_fragment();
            args.putString("url", BaseURL.GET_SUPPORT_URL);
            args.putString("title", getResources().getString(R.string.nav_terms));
            fm.setArguments(args);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            shareApp();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            sessionManagement.logoutSession();
            finish();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_powerd) {
            // stripUnderlines(textView);
            String url = "http://bhavyabharath.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        if (fm != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        try {
            super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check your internet connection

Comment: internet is working fine

Comment: only some devices getting this error

Comment: enable debugging and narrow down the issue. We can't inspect all your code

Comment: where i can see enable debugging